# gridview selector in android. how?

Tags: android, gridview

i am having a gridview. when i select it, the selector(orange color) will shows like square. i want to set that as rounded corners. how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom selector drawable.  You can use the [android:listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector) property.